# How can i use jquery owlCarousel in Angular 4 Project

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, owl-carousel

i have my 'carousel.js' file as

```
$('#owl-carousel-1').owlCarousel({...});
```

and carousel.component.html as:

```
<div id="owl-carousel-1" class="owl-carousel owl-theme center-owl-nav home- 
carousel">....</div>
```

i have called 'carousel.js' file in carousel.component.ts as:

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
  require("../../../assets/js/carousel.js");
}
```

it's work once and once again not work !!!

can anyone help me ... thanks ...

Comment: Instead of importing file , just write the js code into your component

Comment: or else import this file in your index.html file throughout.

Comment: not working when i defined it in component like: $('#owl-carousel-1').owlCarousel({...})

Comment: Why do not use ngx-slider via npm?

Comment: This is ( html, css, js files) template and i'm working on it by angular 4 project, i would like to know how to implement those without any change in design ...

Answer (score 2):

You should follow below steps to use it in npm based angular project
**Install npm module**

```
npm install --save owl.carousel

npm install jquery
```

**Include js flies in angular-cli.json scripts sections and declare them.**

```
  "styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.min.css",
    "../node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "../node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/owl.carousel.min.js"
  ],
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="owl-carousel" #carousel>
  <div> Your Content 1 </div>
  <div> Your Content 2 </div>
  <div> Your Content 3 </div>
  <div> Your Content 4 </div>
  <div> Your Content 5 </div>
  <div> Your Content 6 </div>
  <div> Your Content 7 </div>
</div>
```

for Jquery

```
declare var $: any;
```

Then use `.owlCarousel({...}` to apply **owlCarousel**.

**Component.ts**

```
import { Component, AfterContentInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
declare var $: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterContentInit{

  @ViewChild('carousel') el:ElementRef;
  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    console.log(this.el);
    $(this.el.nativeElement).owlCarousel();
  }
}
```

Here is the [Github Link](https://github.com/nitishkumar71/OwlCarouselExample) for an working example.

Comment: Also not working !! thank you for your efforts and good cooperation, i will try again ...

Answer (score 1):

**This is my code...**

**index.component.html**

```
<div #carousel id="owl-carousel-1" class="owl-carousel owl-theme center-owl-nav home- 
carousel">

<article *ngFor="let sliderPost of allMainSliderPosts; let i = index;" class="article thumb-article">

    <div class="article-img">
        <img [src]="defaultImgPath + sliderPost.img" alt="{{commService.limitString(sliderPost.title, 105)}}">
    </div>

    <div class="article-body">
        <ul class="article-info">
            <li class="article-category">
                <a href="javascript:;">{{sliderPost.category_name}}</a>
            </li>
            <li class="article-type">
                <i *ngIf="sliderPost.post_type === 'videos' || sliderPost.post_type === 'photos-library'" class="fa fa-camera"></i>
                <i *ngIf="sliderPost.post_type === 'posts'" class="fa fa-file-text"></i>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <h2 class="article-title">
            <a routerLink="/p/{{sliderPost.slug}}">
                {{commService.limitString(sliderPost.title, 80)}}
            </a>
        </h2>

    </div>
</article>
```

**index.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, AfterContentInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

declare var $: any;
....
export class IndexComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
@ViewChild('carousel') el: ElementRef;
....
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    $(this.el.nativeElement).owlCarousel(
    {
    loop: true,
    margin: 0,
    dots: false,
    nav: true,
    rtl: true,
    navText: ['<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>', '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"> 
           </i>'],
    autoplay: true,
    responsive: {
      0: {
        items: 1
      },
      992: {
        items: 2
      },
    }
  }
  );
}

}
```

**Finally, The problem still exists !!**

Answer (score 1):

The best solution and the one that works for me is:

1. Create a method that will call your Owl Carousel 
   Jquery

   `carousel() {
      /* carousel code */
   }`
2. Use setTimeout and call the function `setTimeout(carousel, 5000)`, this calls the function after 5 seconds, you may play with the values to see which one works best for you
3. Place setTimeout depending on your situation:

   - if you have local pictures (i.e. A defined array ) place it on `ngOnInit`,
   - if you're consuming a service to recover image data then place the timer in the response, so that your array is filled first and then the jquery is executed

Cheers!

Ps: this solution is oriented so you may use ngfor on your carousel

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling the service for Data from database in ngOnIntIt() then instead of this, you can call all metadata **in router resolve way - "resolve service"** so before component initiate data will be ready with you.